# angular 14 can't access response values as sent from dotnet core 6 CreateAtAction

Tags: angular, .net-core, mat-dialog

Angular 14/dotnet core 6... (aside: the frontend is in MatDialog when this is executed)
I send a simple post request, which works (database is updated correctly):

```
    [Route("CreateProject")]
[HttpPost("{dto}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectAPIDto>> CreateProject(ProjectAPIDto dto)
{
    Project project = _mapper.Map<Project>(dto);

    await _projectsRepository.AddAsync(project);

    ProjectAPIDto projectAPIDto = new ProjectAPIDto();
    projectAPIDto = _mapper.Map<ProjectAPIDto>(project);

    return CreatedAtAction("GetProject", new { Id = projectAPIDto.Id }, projectAPIDto);
}
```

(Frontend is below).  Frontend has "ProjectDto.ts" ... first few lines:

```
export class ProjectDto
{
    public  Id!: number;
    public  Title!:  string;
```

You can see the backend calls it ProjectAPIDto... first few lines:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Hunter.API.DTOs
{
    public class ProjectAPIDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
```

In the backend code above, I went out of my way to map "project" (which has all lowercase like "id" and "title", ...) back to the ProjectAPIDto.
Frontend w/chrome dev tools upon return from the backend:
[Snapshot of dev tools response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYzNJ.png)

Note: the response has the data, but in the "Project" class lowercase (like the database fields) and obviously, response was not cast to ProjectDto.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: That is how a .NET Core API will return a result by default; JSON formatted in camel case. Change your typescript class property names to camel case and your data will get mapped to the class as expected. This is a very well known thing.

Comment: Thanks ... yes, it works just fine now.  I thought I could force Pascal, but camel is fine with me.  Thanks again!